# Selecting a specific td of a specific tr that both have dynamic ids

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get a specific td of a specific tr in a table. Then I use `console.log` to show the value of that td but the result is undefined. I have already used few sample codes but none are working. Here is the last code that I am using and still not getting any values back. I suspect that I am using the function wrongly. Just as extra information, I am using dynamic ids for both tr and td. I appreciate any comments or code sample:

```
function addProduct() {
    $('#myTableId tr "#cart_"+ cart_id +""').each(function() {

         var book_name = $(this).find("#book_"+ book_id +"").html();  
         console.log(book_name);
}
```

I only want to take the tr of the table body. I do not want to select the table header row and table footer roow but the above function is selection all the rows!

AddProduct funtion is trigered when a button is clicked. THe button will append one tr to the table!

Comment: can you show us the full js code and the html?

Comment: What starts you looking for this? if it's an event that occurs in the row, is easier to traverse

Comment: @MrBearAndBeer, the whole js is actually one function for now.

Comment: @charlietfl, yes there is one event where a button is clicked and few information such as book name and quantity is appended to this table. While doing that I want to get the name of the book from that td in that tr.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't concatenating the selectors properly. Try:

```
$('#myTableId tr#cart_' + cart_id).each(function() {
     var book_name = $(this).find('#book_' + book_id).html();  
     console.log(book_name);
});
```

Side note:

- I removed the space between `tr#cart_` because I presume that the `tr` elements have the `id`.

Comment: your sample code is also having th same problem and does not return anything!

Comment: @MaryJane You need to provide more context then. Please make an [example](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: There is one event where a button is clicked addProduct is called and few information such as book name and quantity is appended to this table. While doing that I want to get the name of the book from that td in that tr. The only java script that I am using is what I have written above.

Answer (score 0):

Believe me, if you give an `ID` for every cart, ofcourse you have carts that unique. so just :

```
var book_name = $('#myTableId #book_" +book_id).html();
console.log(book_name);
```

Make `addProduct()` simpler :

```
function addProduct(book_id){
     var book_name = $('#myTableId #book_"+ book_id).html();
     console.log(book_name);
}
```

Comment: I tried your sample code and still returns undefined in stead of the real value. Any idea?

Comment: maybe make the selector shorter would give a way. Check the edit

Comment: I tried the edited code again but no idea why it is not working, I suspect that the selector has issue! Any suggestion?